# How to define keystore for kafka in Big Data tool connections idea plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I can't to connect with Kafka by ssl
I can do it with simple kafka on remote server using Big Data tool connections plugin, but when I try to connect with another Kafka with keystore - plugin requires properties

I tried to define it like this

```
   ssl.keystore.type=PKCS12 
   ssl.keystore.location=/Users/username/workspace/project/cert/namespace/client/me.p12 
   ssl.keystore.password=111111 
   ssl.truststore.location=/Users/username/workspace/project/cert/namespace/client/me.p12 
   ssl.truststore.password=111111 
   ssl.truststore.type=PKCS12
```

But it doen't help. How to configure this plugin?

Comment: I'd recommend you discuss this issue with the plugin development team here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/BDIDE

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? If so, then you should write the file path like this:

```
ssl.keystore.location=C:\\Users\\username\\workspace\\project\\cert\\namespace\\client\\me.p12
```